# What are the rankings in Half Minute Hero, and what determines which one I receive?

Tags: half-minute-hero

I'm confused when I receive medals -- which is better, True Hero or Wonderful Hero? Is there anything better than either of these two ratings? What's the full list of rankings one can achieve on a quest, and what determines which ranking I receive on a given quest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hero 30** mode ranks (best to worst):

- Wonderful Hero
- True Hero
- Balanced Hero
- Little Hero
- Sucky Hero

What rank you get is based on time it takes for you to beat the level and how many of the Titles (E.g. Barely, Kelp Lover) you picked up on the way.

**Evil Lord 30** mode ranks (best to worst):

- Beautiful Evil Lord
- Pretty Evil Lord
- Plain Evil Lord

Your rank is determined by how fast you beat the level.

**Knight 30** mode ranks (best to worst):

- Great Knight
- Big Knight
- Knight
- Mini Knight
- Petite Knight

Your rank is determined by how fast you beat the level. Protecting the Sage is important here, because the more hits the Sage takes, the longer the casting time will be.

**Princess 30** mode is bit different than the other modes as There are five "best" ranks instead of just one best rank. Although the best rank is considered to be "30 Second," there are some levels where getting under 30 seconds is next to impossible (E.g., Level 12, Beach Trip). So that's where the other four "best" ranks come in.

- Best Rank A - 30 Second (Complete level in under 30 seconds)
- Best Rank B - Flawless (Complete the level without losing a single soldier)
- Best Rank C - Fighter (Kill most of the enemies in the level)
- Best Rank D - Gorgeous
- Best Rank E - Legendary
- Blueblood
- Royalty
- Infamous
- Royal Brat

Your rank is determined by how fast you beat the level, how many soldiers got hit in the level, and how many enemies you killed in the level.